# PCRE - Using .* with a lookbehind

Tags: regex, pcre, lookbehind

I am trying to extract the MESSAGE only from the following strings:

```
nbsp;","SUBJECT1","MESSAGE1",0,"
nbsp;","SUBJECT2","MESSAGE2",1,"
```

My PRCRE regex looks like this and works ok for the first record:

```
(?<=nbsp;","SUBJECT1",")(.*?)(?=",(0|1),")
```

However I need to replace SUBJECT with .* so that I can return all messages, no matter what the subject.

When I try using .* i always get the error "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width". I am new to regex and have not found a solution. Help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use the `\K` feature, but I think that regex is the wrong way for the structured data you are trying to parse. You should show how they really look like. Is it a csv file?

Comment: Extract is from txt files (lots of them), sample below. Need separate Subject / Message fields:

["151e059a057e9fec","151e059a057e9fec","151e059a057e9fec",0,0,["^all","^hunsub","^i","^smartlabel_promo","^unsub","^us"],["^all","^cob-processed-gmr","^cob_taskreq","^hunsub","^i","^io_unim","^os_promo","^smartlabel_promo","^sq_ig_i_promo","^u","^unsub","^us"],"<span class=\"zF\" email=\"email@addresscom\" name=\"ASUS\">ASUS</span>","&raquo;&nbsp;","Subject","Message",0,"","","12/26/15","Sat, Dec 26, 2015 at 2:12 PM",1451167949734000,,[],,0,[],,[],,"1",[0],,"email@address",,,,1,0]

Comment: Post that in the question, not in comment. Add also a tag for the language you use.

Comment: Why do you need lookarounds at all? Just [`nbsp;","[^"]+","([^"]+)",([01]),"`](https://regex101.com/r/2EPpJp/1) would be fine to extract, wouldn't it.